# Django: How to check if a user has signed up within the last 7 days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to allow users to have access to my app for 7 days after they register with this function:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.timezone import localdate

    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
        def free_trial(self):
            if (self.date_joined - timezone.now()) < timedelta(days=7):
                return True
```

But testing with accounts made more than 7 days ago i can still see the h1 tag below

```
  {% if user.free_trial %}
    <h1> Your trial has started </h1>
    
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subtract the current `datetime()` from the `self.date_joined`, not the opposite way, otherwise it will be *minus* seven days, which is always less than seven days, so:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
    def free_trial(self):
        return (timezone.now() - self.date_joined) < timedelta(days=7)
```